# How can I disable and mark Shopware 6 config field as obsolete?

Tags: xml, plugins, shopware, shopware6, admin-interface

How can I disable and mark Shopware 6 config field as obsolete? Hello, I am new to shopware. I have a plugin that has a config field I want to disable it mark it as obsolete.

`config.xml`

```xml
<input-field>
  <name>shippingOption</name>
</input-field>
```

Is it even possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can add `disabled` and `helpText` field to your `input-field` like:

```xml
<input-field>
  <name>shippingOption</name>
  <disabled>true</disabled>
  <helpText>This setting is obsolete. </helpText>
</input-field>
```

Kindly, have a look at this [link](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration.html).